# How to prevent Electron app from interrupting macOS system shutdown?

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, operating-system, electron

I have an Electron based app that runs in the macOS menu bar/the Windows tray area.

On Windows a system shutdown exits the app, but on macOS a system shutdown is interrupted due to the app not closing. How can I detect a shutdown event and close the app when the user has not explicitly requested the app to close?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Simple solution:**

```js
import { app, powerMonitor } from 'electron';

powerMonitor.on('shutdown', () => {
  app.quit();
});
```

Comment: As their documentation write, It just work on Linux and darwin NOT for Windows

Answer (score 0):

Check the electron 'app' module documentation [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/app.md).

You can listen to the following events like 'before-quit' and 'will-quit' in order to handle the state of your application. Mind the note that this events won't fire in a Windows environment.

And always be sure that your application handles the 'quit' event in your main process like this

```
app.on('quit', () => {
  app.quit();
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but the issue is that the app is not beginning the process of quitting, so those will not fire. They also are, to my knowledge, available on Windows.

Comment: Would it be possible to share your electron main file?